# eclipse 4.13.0 - dependency repository

Tags: spring, eclipse, maven

I recently downloaded eclipse ee so I can learn more about Java Spring Framework. I am certain that I installed the correct Spring IDE plugin and a Maven Integration plugin is already pre-installed, I double checked. I ran into the issue when I began a new Maven project and I tried adding Spring Dependencies in the pom.xml file. It seems as if eclipse is not looking in the Global Repository because it cannot find any dependencies from the Spring Framework.

I've tried looking online for a solution. Most posts say to check the preferences on Maven and make sure to select the 'Download repository index updates on starup'. I tried that but still no luck.

If anyone has a solution please let me know

[pom.xml screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcKzk.png)

Comment: Show your code (`pom.xml`) and tell which error message you get after which steps where. It is also unclear how the Spring plug-in is related here and which one you have installed (STS 3 or 4 of which version?).

Comment: Im not getting an error. Eclipse is not allowing me to search for Spring dependencies for any of my projects. I made sure Maven is running, I think glassfish is running as well, and I also have tomcat running

Comment: _"Eclipse is not allowing me..."_?! What do you mean by that? Your `pom.xml` does not contain Spring dependencies.